# Internal pressure, but from other variables

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

The internal pressure is derived by differentiating internal energy with respect to the natural variable in one term while holding the unnatural variable in the other term constant.

$$\mathrm dE = T\,\mathrm dS - P\,\mathrm dV \tag{1}$$

becomes

$$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial V}\right)_T = T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T - P\tag{2}$$

Then, using the relevant Maxwell relation, it becomes

$$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial V}\right)_T = T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V - P = \pi_T \tag{3}$$

This procedure is easily modified. For instance,

$$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}\right)_P = T - P\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)_P \tag{4}$$

Again using a Maxwell relation,

$$\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}\right)_P = T + P\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)_S \tag{5}$$

This procedure can be cycled through the various variables in $H,$ $A,$ and $G$ to produce another six expressions (excluding the ones possible with the mole-chemical potential pair).

Do these expressions also have names like internal pressure? If so, what are they?

Comment: What is difference between natural and unnatural variables ? As I have not met such terms yet. Do you mean directly measurable versus computed ?

Comment: The only examples I can recall are not on your list and are isothermal compressibility $\displaystyle\alpha \equiv \frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P$ and bulk modulus $\displaystyle\kappa \equiv-\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_T$

Comment: The natural variables of a function are those that, when held constant, maximize or minimize the function. For example, E is minimized at constant T, P, and u (chem potential). A is minimized at constant S, P and u, etc.

Comment: Isothermal compressibility and bulk modulus are completely different concepts.

Comment: There is an analogous expression for the enthalpy, $\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\right)_T =V- T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p$, but I don't know that it has a name. It is related to the Joule-Thomson coefficient as $-\mu_{JT}C_p$

Comment: @Buck Thorn Exactly! I'm just seeing if anyone knows if these things have names. I realize they aren't as important as the internal pressure, but they might still have names.